# How to iterate cells in a Google sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a solution to automatically detect conflicts in a schedule created with Google sheets. A "conflict" means that in the same day at the same time different lessons are supposed to have same teacher or to be in the same room. For instance, in the table below groups 1 and 2 are supposed to be in room 2 at the same time, which should be indicated as "conflict".

```
                           Monday                              Tuesday                ...
              room   subject   teacher   tutor     room   subject   teacher   tutor   ...
(group1)
09:00-10:00    1     math      Smith     Black
10:00-10:45    2     science   Stones    Moore
...
(group2)
10:00-10:45    2     math      Smith     Taylor
10:55-11:40    1     reading   Anderson  Harris
...
```

To check if there are any "same teacher" conflicts, I've added the following formula:

```
=if(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(D7={D19;D29}));"at this time teacher has another class for _ group";"ok")
```

However, such solution has some drawbacks.

The main one is: the `{D19;D29;...}` array is formed manually which is not nice, at least very fragile. If a line is added in the middle of the schedule, most of the checks will break. What I want to do instead is to get the necessary lines by filtering those with the same time in column A and then get cells D to compare.

Another one is, I can't get (and show) the "conflicting" group which this teacher also is supposed to teach (unless I manually create another array, corresponding to `{D19;D29;...}` which is more manual work), see `_` in the formula.

My question is, can I create some form of loop/iterating in Google sheets to deal with this issues in some convenient coding manner? Or may be you'd suggest another approach to this?

Comment: Here is a blank sheet created specifically for this question.  I'd be a lot easier to help visualize and work on the problem if you pasted in some sample data there in a way that would be representative of the real thing.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OJZrHr_xSHWVFhZVA1GxCxK0_KsXe-eNuziWuk3FqOA/edit

Comment: @MattKing hi, that's quite unexpected approach, I've adapted and inserted sample data, thanks

Comment: I believe I have something, but would like to confirm i understand before I post it as a useful solution.  Can you take a look at Column J? try purposefully creating some conflicts in column A to see if they appear as conflicts.

Comment: Are you open for an apps script solution to highlight conflicting schedules between groups?

Comment: @MattKing oh, my! The result looks very much like what's needed (only room conlicts should also be indicated) but the code looks terrible! This can be indeed accepted as an answer, but an extended explanation will be very helpful

Comment: @RonM apps script can surely be used and can probably provide a more sane solution, the only thing to take care is: a user shouldn't rerun script manually, conflicts should be shown automatically as they edit the schedule

Comment: @YakovL are the times in column A fixed?  If they will never change over the course of a year, the code would be significantly simpler to write.

Comment: @MattKing well, such changes are unlikely, and I've copied your solution for that complicated case, so I can return to it when needed, so it's safe to use a simpler one and I'd do so. PS: such assistance deserves many thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tab on the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OJZrHr_xSHWVFhZVA1GxCxK0_KsXe-eNuziWuk3FqOA/edit#gid=1481590048) called Conflict Finder (Simpler) where you will find this formula in cell G3, and a very similar one in H3.
It counts instances of a common timeslot and teacher name and if it's more than 1, it outputs the word "Conflict"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Teacher Conflicts";IF(COUNTIFS($A4:$A;$A4:$A;D4:D;D4:D)>1;"Conflict";)})
```

Once columns with the array formula are created, you can apply conditional formatting with custom formula to highlight the conflicting cells and hide the auxiliary columns. For instance, for range `D4:D1000` apply `=LEN(G4)` to give red background (in fact, range `D4:E1000` also works since column `H` contains conflicts for column `E`).

Comment: bravo! Simple and effective. Thanks for all the alternatives and hints, the conditional formatting trick is especially practical!

Comment: If you don't object, I'll add the important bits about your suggestions into your answer; I'll mention them in comments otherwise.

Comment: @YakovL feel free to edit the answer!

Comment: while I've elaborated the formula for more complicated cases (like conflicts of the same person supposed to teach one group and tutor another at the same time), I wonder if it can be move to just custom formatting, so I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69393746/3995261 I'll be glad if you take a look