# How to combine these arrayformula and formula in custom formatting rule in just 1 formula in custom formatting rule?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using an array formula to find conflicts in a schedule. In a simplified form, it looks like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Teacher Conflicts";IF(COUNTIFS($A4:$A;$A4:$A;B4:B;B4:B)>1;"Conflict";)})
```

where column A contains time slots and B contains teacher names, like

```
group 1                 Teacher Conflicts
10:00-10:45  Smith      Conflict
11:00-11:45  Black
12:00-12:45  Anderson
...
group 2
10:00-10:45  Smith      Conflict
11:00-11:45  White
12:00-12:45  Hardy
...
```

Now, to make it more handy to use, I also use conditional formatting (the whole solution was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69209359/3995261) by MattKing) with formula just `=len(C4)` to highlight conflicting cells and hide the C column.

As one can see, the second formula is quite simple, so looks like I can move the whole thing into custom formatting like this:

```
=len(IF(COUNTIFS($A4:$A;$A4:$A;B4:B;B4:B)>1;"Conflict";))
```

(can be simplified to `=COUNTIFS($A4:$A;$A4:$A;B4:B;B4:B)>1`, but I just copy-pasted the cell bit to make this clearer; it's not the point here)

The problem is, it doesn't work the same! It highlights different cells. I'm guessing the reason is, in `arrayformula` and in custom formatting formula, the meaning of the first and the second `$A4:$A`s are different, but I'm not sure how to correct those and how exactly custom formatting formula is read differently. I hope, the expected behavior is clear enough, so the question is, how do I modify the custom formatting formula to get that?

PS here's an [MVCE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBcfzunl1x4T63FUvaXYQlREs6EfHckZGiu_ytDNniU/edit?usp=sharing). The formula is a bit more complicated, founds cross-conflicts when the same person is supposed to be a tutor and a teacher at the same time; this actually gives some insights about the source of the problem, compared to simple conflicts. If (in the experiments tab) you try to substitute custom formatting formula `=len(D3)` with `(COUNTIFS($A3:$A;$A3:$A;B3:B;B3:B) + COUNTIFS($A3:$A;$A3:$A;C3:C;B3:B))>1`, you'll notice that 2 conflicts are no longer highlighted.

PPS Some more experimenting gave me a hypothesis: looks like the ranges in `countifs` inside custom formatting formula are not actually `B4:B` but rather `Bn:B` where n is the row number of the formatted cell. Not sure how to check this and if it's possible to fix this. Yet.

Comment: The `COUNTIFS` will simply check if there are duplicates in Col `A` & `B` via `ARRAYFORMULA` (the `$A4:$A,$A4:$A` is the `criteria_range1, criterion1` then B4:B;B4:B is the `criteria_range2, criterion2`). If there are duplicate schedule times found on col `A` & also duplicate names found on col `B`, then the result of `COUNTIFS` is `> 1`, that's how the function work to find a conflict in schedule. But on your test sheet on col `A`, you have multiple schedule times added as `17.00-17.45` or `16:00-16.45` (with `.` instead of a colon `:` symbol). Is your real sheet data contains the same data?

Comment: @IrvinJayG. in the real data the time ranges are formatted as shown above. If you are referring to the sheet attached to the linked answer, well, I'm not sure why there are time ranges formatted like you've mentioned, but that one was modified by MattKing and may be somebody else (it's editable for anyone), so don't take it too seriously.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying and my apologies for over analyzing your data.

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION

You can try & test this custom formula below that you can add on the `Conditional format rules` settings.

```
=countifs($A$4:$A,A4,$B$4:$B,B4) > 1
```

### Sample

[image]

Comment: If this fully answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I've tested this before and for some reason it doesn't work – it highlights a different set of rows (for the current data – a subset; in the question I wrote highlights more, but it seems I just pointed an incorrect column at that point). I have no idea why, that's why I asked

Comment: here's an MVCE: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBcfzunl1x4T63FUvaXYQlREs6EfHckZGiu_ytDNniU/edit?usp=sharing (the formula is a bit more complicated, founds cross-conflicts when the same person is supposed to be a tutor and a teacher at the same time; this actually gives some insights about the source of the problem, compared to simple conflicts). If (in the experiments tab) you try to substitute custom formatting formula `=len(D3)` with `(COUNTIFS($A3:$A;$A3:$A;B3:B;B3:B) + COUNTIFS($A3:$A;$A3:$A;C3:C;B3:B))>1`, you'll notice that 2 conflicts are no longer highlighted